# need a better and efficient way

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native, node-api

```html
   exports.Country = async (req, res, err) => {

  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err)
      send.json({ message: err.message, statuscode: err.status });
    var dbo = db.db(DATABASE);
    dbo.collection("countries").find({}, { projection: { _id: 0, iso2: 1, name: 1, } }).toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.json({ message: err.message, statuscode: err.Response })
      };
      res.json({ success: true, statuscode: 200, response: result });
      db.close();
    })
  })
}
```

Hi everyone it is working fine but i think there should be a better way can someone suggest
NOTE:I am doing this crud operations on a collection which does not have any schema i just imported json collection to my database

Comment: You are retrieving the entire collection in your query.  Is that intended?

Comment: yes it is and my question is can we do any better way of accessing db and collection whenever we needed?

Comment: Time to retrieve docs is composed of IO, storage, and query time (amongst others).  Hopefully you can limit the IO time by using an appropriate `find`/`aggregation` query so that only the docs of interest need to be returned.  Make MongoDB server do as much of the work as possible.  You can look at `explain` results to see how the server is spending it's time, etc.  In general, retrieving an entire collection should be avoided - it's just using the DB as storage with no effective query.